# CRM 2011, service calendar delayed refresh

Tags: calendar, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

In CRM 2011, if I create a new service and assign resources to it, then I change the resource on the service and refresh, I still see the old version of the service calendar.

In short - it does not get updated immediately.

Is this a general problem with the CRM 2011 service calendar or something specific to our organization?

Answer (score 0):

What sort of time lag are you experiencing? Does it get refreshed at all?

From memory, I think the refresh is handled by the Async service. You should check that that the service is started and running. If it is running, you should check if the load on your server suggests that the Async service is too busy (e.g. do you have lots of workflows running?).

Comment: No we havent got lots workflows. It has been changeable, i saw a lot different time. 2 seconds,one hour, one day. I could not understand anything.

Comment: Are there any plugins registered on your server? Can you try restarting the Asynchronous Processing Service to see if that alleviates the problem?

Comment: I think it is a general problem about crm 2011. Because we use crm 2011 two different company but the situation is same.